# "unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING" error when printing Chinese word

Tags: r, encoding

I tried to run a simple command in R, as a script, like this one

```
print("寛")
```

And R gives me an error like this:

> Error in source(con, echo = echo, print.eval = print.eval, max.deparse.length = max.deparse.length,  : 
>     con:2:7: unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING

I guess this is some kind of encoding issue, and that Chinese word is exactly what I need to use in R. What can I do?

Comment: You should check that the encoding used by your locale (add `sessionInfo()` to your script to see it) and used to save the file are the same, and allow Chinese characters. It works, for instance, with UTF8.

Comment: I tried but the error message pops out as `Warning message:
In Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "UTF-8") :
  OS reports request to set locale to "UTF-8" cannot be honored`

Comment: That is only the encoding half of the locale. The following may work: `Sys.setlocale("LC_CTYPE", "en_GB.UTF-8")`.