# R encoding error with source but not in console

Tags: r, character-encoding, rstudio

I am having some strange Encoding problems when using sourcing in R-Studio, but not when directly ctrl+enter while developing the script.  Basically, I'm creating a data.frame storing words from different languages along with their english translation.  This works fine until I source.  I realize this may be Encoding problems, but I am really not sure how to proceed, nor do I fully understand why the error I get (unexpected INCOMPLETE_STRING) only occurs with source. Do I need to change the encoding before each language change?  How do I know which encoding will be the correct one?

Thanks for any help. Here is the code:

```
translator = data.frame('RESULT' = character(),'english' = character(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

translator[1,] = c('Completed','Completed') #English
translator[2,] = c('Failed','Failed') #English
translator[3,] = c('User canceled','Canceled') #English

translator[4,] = c('完了','Completed') #chinese
translator[5,] = c('已完成','Completed') #Chinese
translator[6,] = c('失败','Failed') #Chinese
translator[7,] = c('用户取消','Canceled') #Chinese

translator[8,] = c('ユーザーによる取り消し','Canceled') #japanese
translator[9,] = c('エラー','Failed') #japanese

translator[10,] = c('Completata','Completed') #Italian
translator[11,] = c('Fallita','Failed') #Italian
translator[12,] = c('Annullata','Canceled') #Italian

translator[13,] = c('Finalizado','Completed') #Spanish
translator[14,] = c('Cancel usuario','Canceled') #Spanish
translator[15,] = c('Fallido','Failed') #Spanish
translator[16,] = c('Cancelado utili.','Canceled') #Spanish

translator[17,] = c('Terminé','Completed') #French
translator[18,] = c('Annulé par utilis.','Canceled') #French
translator[19,] = c('Echoué','Failed') #French

translator[20,] = c('Abgeschlossen','Completed') #German
translator[21,] = c('Benutzerabbruch','Canceled') #German
translator[22,] = c('Fehlgeschlagen','Failed') #German

translator[23,] = c('Concluído','Completed') #Portuguese
translator[24,] = c('Falhado','Failed') #Portuguese

translator[25,] = c('Doko','Completed') #Czech
translator[26,] = c('Zru','Canceled') #Czech

translator[27,] = c('Chyba','Failed') #Polish

translator[28,] = c('Отмена','Canceled') #Russian
translator[29,] = c('Готово','Completed') #Russian
translator[30,] = c('Ошибка','Failed') #Russian
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'INCOMPLETE_STRING' most likely means that the encoding / locale is not set for the characters in the file.  These two links may help:

[How to source() .R file saved using UTF-8 encoding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding)

[unexpected-incomplete-string-error-when-printing-chinese-word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8889262/unexpected-incomplete-string-error-when-printing-chinese-word)

Comment: Thank you, the answer was: eval(parse(filename, encoding="UTF-8"))  from a post at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031630/how-to-source-r-file-saved-using-utf-8-encoding